# Discord Python: Adding a role to a member

Tags: python, discord.py

My bot checks whenever a user is added to a guild on Discord and then privately DMs them for their email address. It then sends a one-time code to the email address and asks the user to enter the code in the DM. All this is implemented and works. However, when the user answers with the code, I cannot seems to be able to assign a new role to the user. Here is what I currently have (I removed the code that checks the one-time code, etc. as it works and does not seem to be the source of the problem):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if message was sent by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Check if the message was a DM
    if message.channel.type != discord.ChannelType.private:
        return

    user_code = 'some code sent via email'

    if message.content == user_code:
        member = message.author

        new_guild = client.get_guild(int(GUILD_ID))
        role = get(new_guild.roles, id=DISCORD_ROLE)
        await member.add_roles(role)

        response = "You can now use the Discord Server."
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 89, in on_message
    await member.add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: Edited: It appears your `GUILD_ID` is incorrect and is not a valid guild id

Comment: I just added the error I receive. GUILD_ID is defined in an .env file and I have checked manually that it is the correct id.

Comment: If it is stored external, can you just confirm that is an int? ie just try `int(GUILD_ID)` on the get_guild line

Comment: `new_guild` has not been recognised. Are you sure that `GUILD_ID` is an int and that the bot is on that server?

Comment: So yes, indeed, GUILD_ID wasn't a int. I fixed that, however, I am still getting an error in another line (see my updated post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to transform the [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user) object into a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object. That way, you can call the [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) method. Here is one way of doing it:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if message was sent by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Check if the message was a DM
    if message.channel.type != discord.ChannelType.private:
        return

    user_code = "some code sent via email"

    if message.content == user_code:
        new_guild = client.get_guild(int(GUILD_ID))

        member = new_guild.get_member(message.author.id)
        role = new_guild.get_role(int(DISCORD_ROLE))
        await member.add_roles(role)

        response = "You can now use the Discord Server."
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

Comment: I'm getting another error now: for the line `await member.add_roles(role)`, it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the line where the error is? I did not call `id` at that line. Did you call `role.id`?

Comment: It also says in the traceback that `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)`

Comment: That must be the role. Are you sure this is the valid role id? Maybe try `role = new_guild.get_role(int(DISCORD_ROLE))` instead. I have updated my answer

Comment: Oh, yes, I had the same problem with `GUILD_ID` and `DISCORD_ROLE`... Thank you very much for your help!